# d3js How to draw a line by both ends so it meet at the middle?

Tags: d3.js

I saw we can animate the drawing of stroke via `stroke-dasharray`, such :

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 300);

var path = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", "M10,10 50,20, 100,30 110,40 100,50 50,40 10,10 Z")
  .attr("style", "stroke:#666;stroke-width:6px;fill:none;");

var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + "," + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength) // = eat how much of the black dash ?
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease("linear")
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**But how to draw it such as the two animated lines meet up at the middle ?**

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973267/how-do-i-animate-line-in-d3-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should work :)

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 300);

var path = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", "M0,30 L30,5 L60,30 S70,20 90,7 S120,10 120,30")
  .attr("style", "stroke:#666;stroke-width:6px;fill:none;");

var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + "," + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength) // = eat how much of the black dash ?
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease("linear")
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength * 1/2) // gives the meeting point.
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + "," + 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

It could also work for other ratio than middle, but you must provide this ratio.

Comment: Thanks to the anonymous but heroic +1 giver.