# intersection point of google chart and svg line

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, google-visualization

[Svg line not displayed on google charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397363/svg-line-not-displayed-on-google-charts)

Refering this question i want to find out point at which svg line cuts google chart.

This is fiddle link to http://jsfiddle.net/nc6uf/

i want to find point at which mouse intersects google chart in mouse move event

```
  graph.on('mousemove', function() {
            line.attr("y1", d3.event.y - 50);
            line.attr("y2", d3.event.y - 50);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Each Google Chart is drawn in an SVG that is in its own div. SVG objects can only be drawn within an  element, and since you have two SVG canvases in your example (one on top and one on the bottom) your line will only be drawn in the element to which you appended the line. Because you used d3.select() you selected the first element that satisfied your condition "svg".

You can see the second SVG canvas interact with your mousemove by changing this line in your example:

```
 var graph = d3.select('svg');
```

to:

```
 var graph = d3.selectAll('svg');
```

If you wanted the line to pass through both charts, you'd need the charts to be drawn on the same SVG canvas.

Comment: using your solution line is now drawn on both charts. Any idea on how to find intersection point of svg line with google charts?