# Placement of .transition for lines in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I'm looking to get a transition animation into my line graph, but I'm not really sure where the .transition() would go. I tried to put it in where I thought it should go, but that just froze the graph. Here's my code:

```
            var vis = d3.select('#visual'),
                WIDTH = 1000,
                HEIGHT = 500,
                MARGINS = {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 20,
                    left: 50
                },
                xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                }), d3.max(lineData, function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                })]),
                yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function(d) {
                    return d.y - 1;
                }), d3.max(lineData, function(d) {
                    return d.y;
                })]),

                //setup x
                xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xRange)
                .tickSize(5)
                .tickSubdivide(true),

                //setup y
                yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yRange)
                .tickSize(5)
                .orient("left")
                .tickSubdivide(true);


            vis.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            vis.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
                .call(yAxis);



            var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) {
                    return xRange(d.x);
                })
                .y(function(d) {
                    return yRange(d.y);
                });

            vis.append("svg:path")
                .attr("class", "myLine")
                .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData))
                .attr("stroke", "blue")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("fill", "none");
 //           lineFunc.transition();           <--Where I thought the tag should be
 //           lineFunc.exit().transition()

 //           .remove();
```

And here's the whole thing if necessary: https://jsfiddle.net/hppkqfy7/

Comment: Well, what do you want to transition? Animate the line drawing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893127/how-to-draw-a-path-smoothly-from-start-point-to-end-point-in-d3-js

Comment: No, not quite. In my program, the graphed line can change based on the input from the slider above it. I'm trying to animate the transition for when the slider value is changed and the graph equation and shape changes. In other words, I need a transition for the dynamic shifts.

Comment: Then you just need it before resetting the `d` attribute: https://jsfiddle.net/hppkqfy7/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transitions in D3 usually apply to attribute(s) and `.transition()` should be called before setting the new value of the attribute(s). This will tell D3 to interpolate between old and new.

In your case, you'd call `.transition()` just before setting the updated `d` attribute:

```
d3.select(".myLine")
  .transition()
  .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData));
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hppkqfy7/1/).