# How to draw path with d3 after button click in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working with D3 to try and draw a path after a button is pressed, but I can't get it to work. I am trying to use the technique found here: [How to draw a path smoothly from start point to end point in D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893127/how-to-draw-a-path-smoothly-from-start-point-to-end-point-in-d3-js) but I can't seem to make it work. Here is what I have:

```
//This is the part that I am having trouble with
var expectedPathLength = expectedGraph.node().getTotalLength();

expectedGraph.attr("stroke-dasharray", expectedPathLength + " " + expectedPathLength)
        .attr("stroke-offset", expectedPathLength);
```

Here is the link to my entire program: http://codepen.io/nickpalmer789/pen/xOZQaQ?editors=0010. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The property is `stroke-dashoffset`, you are using `stroke-offset`.  Also, remember to set a fill of `none` on the path.  Voting to close as a typo...

Comment: Updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MeydMa?editors=0010) with fix.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I feel quite dumb now. I agree that the question should be closed.