# D3 line chart, Expected number shows number and NaN

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/NNjlIr?p=preview

I'm trying to create a simple line chart with Angular and D3.

In my example the console show the data but graph dosen't show the line

I get an error in the console.

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,3LNaN,8LNaN,…".

The `NaN` seems to show the correct number with `NaN`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
private drawLine() {

    console.log(this.data);

    this.valueline = d3.line()
        .x((d) => { return d['date']; })
        .y((d) => { return d['total'] });

    this.g.append('path')
        .datum(this.data)
        .attr("class", "path")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", this.valueline(this.data));

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use your scales (`this.x` and `this.y`):

```
this.valueline = d3.line()
    .x((d) => { return this.x(d['date']); })
    .y((d) => { return this.y(d['total']) });
```

Without the scales you are passing things like `"2012-03-20"` to the SVG path's `"d"` attribute, which makes little sense.

Here is the updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/S9UejrvcgVE9yhIHUbkE?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, works perfect. Can I be really cheeky and ask how I might animate the line from left to right,

Comment: Yes, you can ask. However, that's not a simple task. There are a lot of examples online, like this: http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326, and several answers here at S.O., like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13893127/5768908

Answer (score -1):

Please refer the below link this gives lot of implementation,
[D3Js with Angular 2](https://github.com/datencia/d3js-angular2-example)